# Java Class hierarchies with Generics, Comparator and sort error

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I have the following classes:

```
  public interface ISort<T> {
      public List<T> sort(List<T> initialList);
  }


  public abstract class Sort<T> implements ISort<T> {
    private Comparator<? super T> comparator;
   
    public Sort(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> sort(List<T> initialList) {
        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(initialList);
        Collections.sort(list, comparator);
   
        return list;
    }
  }


public abstract class InternalTreeItem<T> {   
    public abstract String getValue();
}

public class D extends InternalTreeItem<Integer> {
   private Integer i;
   
   public D(Integer i) {
       this.i = i;
   }
   
   @Override
   public String getValue() {
       return i.toString();
   }
   
   public Integer getInteger() {
       return i;
   }
}

public class DComparator implements Comparator<D> {
    @Override
    public int compare(D o1, D o2) {
        return o1.getInteger() - o2.getInteger();
    }
}

public class DSort extends Sort<D> {
    public DSort(Comparator<D> comparator) {
        super(comparator);
    }
   
    public DSort() {
        super(new DComparator());
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        List<InternalTreeItem<?>> list= new ArrayList<InternalTreeItem<?>>();
       
        list.add(new D(1));
        list.add(new D(10));
        list.add(new D(5));
       
        ISort<?> sorter = new DSort();
           
        sorter.sort(list);       
    }
}
```

The compiler gives an error at the line:

```
sorter.sort(list);
```

And states:

```
The method sort(List<capture#2-of ?>)
in the type ISort<capture#2-of ?>
is not applicable for the arguments
 (List<InternalTreeItem<?>>)
```

We realized the problem lies with `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` in the abstract class `Sort`, as I use a `Comparator<? extends T>`.

I use generics, as I have 2 models, one model's super class is a generic abstract subclassed by 35 classes, and the second model actually has 2 different super classes, which combined, are subclassed by again 35 classes. These hierarchies are given, there's nothing I can do to modify them.

The model here is very simple, but you get the point. Also, there's a factory, that depending on the type of `T`, returns one sorter, or another.

How can I solve this issue? That is, to sort a generic list; the parameter type can be a generic superclass or one of it's subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this is to use a wrapper class for the classes that you cannot change.

So in your example you want to order a list of object D, based on an Integer value. By putting your objects in a wrapper and then adding this to the list, you can expose the value you wish to sort the list by.

For example, you could define an interface like:

```
private interface SortableListItem<T> extends Comparable<SortableListItem<T>> {
    public T getValue();
}
```

Then, create a wrapper class for D:

```
public class DWrapper implements SortableListItem<Integer> {
    private D item;

    public DWrapper(D item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return item.getInteger();
    }

    public int compareTo(SortableListItem<Integer> o) {
        return getValue().compareTo(o.getValue());
    }
}
```

From here it is pretty simple to create and sort your list:

```
    D item1= new D(1);
    D item2= new D(10);
    D item3= new D(5);

    DWrapper wrapper1 = new DWrapper(item1);
    DWrapper wrapper2= new DWrapper(item2);
    DWrapper wrapper3= new DWrapper(item3);

    List<SortableListItem<Integer>> sortableList = new  ArrayList<SortableListItem<Integer>>();
    sortableList.add(wrapper1 );
    sortableList.add(wrapper2);
    sortableList.add(wrapper3);
    Collections.sort(sortableList);
```

You can of course make the wrapper class accept a more generic object - the key is that each object returns a value (in this case an Integer) that the List can be sorted by.

Comment: Hello RichardP. I like your solution a lot, except that I have two models I should apply this to, that is more than 70 classes :|

Comment: 70 classes, that does sound like a lot of work. If you can write your wrapper classes so that they take instances of the super class instead of writing one wrapper per sub-class, you'd have a lot less work to do.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `sorter` is of type `ISort<?>`. It could have, say, an `ISort<String>` assigned to it. The `sort` method takes an argument of `List<T>` where `T` could be `String`. Clearly you cannot use `List<InternalTreeItem<?>>` for `List<String>`, so fortunately the compiler points out the error.

(Note: It's generally a good idea to keep to coding conventions. No `I` Hungarian prefixes, or single letter class names.)

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for the comment:)
But as I noticed, the compiler points out a different error. As I stated before, the sort method required Comparator to be type parameterized with `? super T`, while I pass to it a type that's actually `? extends T`.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code what I can deduce is that you get a compile error since it is not possible to capture the wildcard that you specify in below line of class *TestClass*:

```
ISort<?> sorter = new DSort();
```

As I understand an occurrence of wild card is taken to stand for some unknown type and from your code it is not possible to infer the type (for the compiler).

But looking at the code, the class DSort is not written in a way to take type parameters
and any attempt to pass type parameters during creation of instance of DSort gave the error:
`The type DSort is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments`

But you mention that you cannot alter the code of the modules (i.e I presume of classes DSort etc).
So one way to fix the error would be to not use generics during creation of instance of ISort.
The below code works and the prints the the sorted output (1,5,10)

```
List<InternalTreeItem<?>> list= new ArrayList<InternalTreeItem<?>>();
list.add(new D(1));
list.add(new D(10));
list.add(new D(5));

// no generic arguments
ISort sorter = new DSort();

List<InternalTreeItem<?>> sortedList = sorter.sort(list);

for(InternalTreeItem i:sortedList) {
    System.out.println(i.getValue());
}
```

but results in a warning of the form *ISort is a raw type. References to generic type ISort should be parameterized*. But having code that uses generic and having warning of this form is not a good practice . This warning implies that the compiler cannot give cast-iron guarantee about the implicit casts it does to use generics.

If feasible, I think the better solution would be to see how the modules class can re-designed.

Comment: Hey sateesh, unfortunately, I cannot modify the model class hierarchies, and by model class hierarchies I refer to the 2 models, where one has a generic class subclassed by 35 classes, and the other one has two top classes.

These hierarchies cannot be changed in any way.

Comment: Maybe then you might have to use raw types (without generics) and live with the warnings

Comment: I don't think that'll be an option :(